# django: using blocks in included templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have some html structures that are reused in quite a few different places. It's different from a overall template so I can't extend it, it can also be used to contain complicated content so I don't think defining it as a template tag does a good job. Below is some **pseudo code** describing my desired outcome, when using template_level2.html you can easily put stuff into the reusable_pattern_template by calling the block inside it. If I do use this code, what you write in 'actual content' of template_level_2.html wouldn't show up. How should I deal with this?

base.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

template_level1.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  Something here...
  {% include 'reusable_pattern_template.html' %}
  Something else here...
{% endblock %}
```

reusable_pattern_template.html

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      {% block local_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

template_level2.html

```
{% extends 'template_level1.html' %}
{% block local_content %}
  Actual content here...
{% endblock %}
```

**update:**
Sorry, the extends in template_level2.html has some misspelling, I've just corrected it.

It may not be very clear, but the code above is more of a pseudo code describing my desired outcome. In short,

- I would like to include small pieces of reusable html patterns in my
  templates.
- These patterns are like boxes, that you can put whole pieces of html
  content in them. So context variables may be a bit of too limited for
  my purpose

Comment: Seems like `template_level2.html`  is never called. And if you `include` some blocks of code, you don't need to use `block` statement as you will include when and what you want

Comment: Hi fastreload! `template_level2.html` is the final level of template so it's not included/extended anywhere. By calling `{% block %}` statement in `template_level2.html`, I intended to put content into `reusable_pattern_template.html`, which is used in `template_level2.html`

Comment: Question: why not use django-generic-flatblocks ? It's a fantastic app which provides a great pattern.

Comment: template_level2.html without quotes is interpreted as variable that must evaluate to string or Template object.
Read more about [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#extends)

Answer (score 71):

Django does not process blocks in included files.

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of "render this subtemplate and include the HTML", not as "parse this subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the parent". This means that there is no shared state between included templates -- each include is a completely independent rendering process. ([Django template tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include))

Comment: Variables from view are still shared and parsed, though.

Comment: Context is also given to the included templates (That may be the same as the above comment, but 'context' is more recognized than Variables From View.)

Comment: Helpful explanation, but _is_ there a tag or other method to do what OP was hoping for? I, too, would like to be able to include a template, and still be able to use template inheritance

Comment: @Chris Pratt What if I want to include a page that has some "model-binding" JS behaviour in a script tag and I don't want <script> tags scattered all over the place ([check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721155/django-templates-including-pages-that-injects-code-into-parent-block))? I think using `include` for this scenario fits well in the presented definition.

Comment: In 2021, There is a way to proccess blocks in included files?

Comment: Amazing... After so many times of reading it... I have just understood what this paragraph is talking about!

Answer (score 12):

I came across this problem and ended up with the following compromise, hoping someone else might find it useful.  It relies on using `with` blocks in the child templates.

*base.html* wants to reuse a common *nav.html* include, but define some blocks where variables inside *nav.html* might be overriden by child templates.

```
<!-- base.html: -->
<html>
  [...]
  <nav class="desktop">
    {% block desktop_nav %}
      {% include "includes/nav.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
  </nav>
  [...]
  <nav class="mobile">
    {% block mobile_nav %}
      {% include "includes/nav.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
  </nav>
  [...]
```

The include template depends on a variable called `selected`, which *base.html* does not define, by default:

```
<!--includes/nav.html:-->
<a href="/about/" class="{% if selected == 'about' %}selected{% endif %}">About</a>
<a href="/people/" class="{% if selected == 'people' %}selected{% endif %}">People</a>
<a href="/contact/" class="{% if selected == 'contact' %}selected{% endif %}">Contact</a>
```

But child pages can override that value as follows:

```
<!--about.html:-->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block desktop_nav %}{% with selected='about' %}{{ block.super }}{% endwith %}{% endblock %}
{% block mobile_nav %}{% with selected='about' %}{{ block.super }}{% endwith %}{% endblock %}
```

so, not perfect, I still have to have two separate blocks and use those `with` blocks twice, but it does allow me to override variables in `include` blocks from the parent template.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the final template is trying to extend itself *(if it was in quotes)*.

You really don't need that much of complexity. It's actually pretty much simpler.

The base template should hold the skeleton of your template, then you can extend it to make customizations. For reusable code blocks that you don't want to include in your every view, `include` them where appropriate but don't use any `block`, `extends` or `include` statement within the included file. Django will not parse those but the `context variable` passed from the view can still be used.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can create variables in whichever template you're planning to include e.g.

```
{{ localcontent }}
```

and then assign those variables wherever you include the template e.g.

```
{% include "name_snippet.html" with localcontent="Actual content" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split reusable_pattern_template into begin and end templates. Then in level1 you can go include begin, block, include end.

Alternatively you could pass a template name into reusable_pattern_template as a context variable and then include it in reusable_pattern_template. This will require changing the relationship between level1 and level2 in your example but is generally more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact thing but you can do this (I've used it for including navigation bars):

Use `with` and `only`

`snippet.html`:

```html
<div>
  {{ listItem1 }}{{ listItem2 }}...{{ listItemN }}
</div>
```

`index.html`:

```html
{% include 'snippet.html' with listItem1='<li>HOME</li>' listItem2 ='<li>ABOUT</li>' only %}
```

Since, we have used `only` after listItem2, all further variables will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do, however, Django does not process blocks in included files... I have a "dirty" solution for you:

Let's suppose you have:
[initial_state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpHf2.png)

This won't be possible since constants.html won't be processed into a new about.html, which will be processed into base.html...

The "dirty" solution:
[possible_solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz1rb.png)

With this, you can re-use the same block as many times as you want, however you will create a new file for each of them...

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.