# django template create blocks in included files

Tags: django, templates, block

I am building a site with quite some different nav_bars depending on what you do.
Now i made for these different nav_bars extra html files that i include in my base.
However I bumped into a problem. I cant seem to create additional blocks in my included file.

Is there a way to do this, so I don't have to make a huge nav_bar inside my base.html?

Example in base.html:

```
{% include "character/character_nav_bar.html" %}
```

and in my character_nav_bar.html:

```
<li {% block charactersheet %}{% endblock %}>
    <a href="{% url 'character_sheet' %}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Character Sheet</a>
</li>
```

and last in my character_sheet.html.

```
{% block charactersheet %}class="active"{% endblock %}
```

(keep in mind this is just a simple example sometimes blocks are used for more then putting a class to active)

Comment: possible duplicate of [django: using blocks in included templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633387/django-using-blocks-in-included-templates)

Comment: Didn't see that one yet. But my question is also, is there some way around it? Maybe with a package or something else?