# Django templates, including page(s) that injects code into parent block

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.8

Is it possible to include a template (with `include` django template tag) within another template and "inject" some content to the page that includes (parent) through `block` tag, or something similar?

Let's say I have the following file structure within my project:

```
App/
    (...)
    templates/
        base.html
        index.html
        _include1.html
        _include2.html
        _include3.html
        _include4.html
```

Code for `base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    (...)
</head>
<body>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(function () {
        {% block extra_script %}
        {% endblock %}
    });

</script>
```

Code for `index.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
(...)
<div class="row gutter">
    <div>
        {% include "_include1.html" with object=object%}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% include "_include2.html" with object=object %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% include "_include3.html" with object=object %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% include "_include4.html" with object=object %}
    </div>
</div>
```

And in each `_include*.html` I would like to call some specific JS function (for example), but I want to place it in the parents (`index.html` or `base.html`, doesn't matter in my case) `extra_script` block. I searched in the documentation, other questions and didn't find a way to do this with the `include` syntax.

I've done something similar but through `extends` tag. However I don't want to define a block in the `index.html` or `base.html` for each page that I need to include (`{% bloc include_* %}`.

So the solution that I have now (and works) is to define a script in each included page like this (`_include1.html`):

```
<div>
(...)
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        //Code that should be placed within parents script page (this is just an example)
        var a = function (){
                    (...)
                };
        a();
    });
</script>
```

However I think there's a better way to do this, by making use of django templates engine, and without having to define a block for each page that needs to be included. Also I would like to have all my js code in a single place (parents `<script>` tag) instead of being scattered all over the place (like it is with the presented solution).

Can anyone give some input or ideas towards this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [django-sekizai](https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for that purpose.

With sekizai, you can define a JavaScript block just before the `</body>`:

```
{% render_block "js" %}
```

And then whenever you need to add JavaScript to that block, you write this:

```
{% addtoblock "js" %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // your JavaScript
    </script>
{% endaddtoblock %}
```

If there are duplicates of the content in the {% addtoblock %} blocks, they will be used only once.

Comment: I'll check into this, Thanks!