# Refactoring part of template into own file breaks django

Tags: django

I have something weird:
I got a `base.html` that acts as a skeleton with blocks for the website.
It contains this part:

```html
<main class="main">
  {% block main %}
    <div class="content">
      {% block content %}
        content
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
</main>
```

I also got a `base_with_sidebar.html` that looks like this:

```html
{% extends "core/base.html" %}

{% block main %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <div class="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
      {% include "polls/recent_polls.html" %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and `index.html` which fills the content:

```html
{% extends "app/base_with_sidebar.html" %}
{% block content %}
  somecontent
{% endblock %}
```

This all works so far.

The problem arises if I want to refactor `base.html`:
from this:

```html
<main class="main">
  {% block main %}
    <div class="content">
      {% block content %}
        content
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
</main>
```

to this:
`base.html`

```html
<main class="main">
  {% block main %}
    {% include './main.html' %}
  {% endblock %}
</main>
```

`main.html`

```html
<div class="content">
  {% block content %}
    content
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

This results in my `index.html` always displaying 'content' - instead of the `block content` specified in `index.html`

Comment: Probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636850/5520354

Comment: "The include tag should be considered as an implementation of "render this subtemplate and include the HTML", not as "parse this subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the parent". Ah, thought include would work differently. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't override blocks in included templates:

> Blocks are evaluated before they are included. This means that a template that includes blocks from another will contain blocks that have already been evaluated and rendered - not blocks that can be overridden by, for example, an extending template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include